# How to change live tile size in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to resize the tiles in MetroUI in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/490564/is-there-any-way-to-resize-the-tiles-in-metroui-in-windows-8)

I want my live tile sizes to be different according to their importance to me. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on `Live Tile` and you will get an option to select `larger` and `smaller`

Answer (score 7):

You can right click the tile and make it Larger or Smaller.

[image]

Generally speaking, the larger, rectangular tile provides more information while the smaller, square version is less verbose. To do so, select the tile and then choose Larger (or Smaller) from the app bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the live tile, and at the bottom left you will get an option to select **Larger** or **Smaller**.