# Any way to customize tile size in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, live-tiles

Any way to set a custom tile size via the registry in Windows 8?

Now I don't mean I want to change the tile size of x tile to "small", "medium" or "large". I want to be able to set the exact size of a tile to whatever I damn well please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to resize the tiles in MetroUI in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/490564/is-there-any-way-to-resize-the-tiles-in-metroui-in-windows-8), [How to customize the size of tiles in metro UI?](http://superuser.com/questions/496463/how-to-customize-the-size-of-tiles-in-metro-ui)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are implying, no you cannot. Sorry. Windows has defined tile sizes so the aesthetics are kept streamlined. Tiles are grid bound.

Also, this is a duplicate of the following:

https://superuser.com/questions/496463/how-to-customize-the-size-of-tiles-in-metro-ui

[Is there any way to resize the tiles in MetroUI in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/490564/is-there-any-way-to-resize-the-tiles-in-metroui-in-windows-8)

Comment: So there's no way to change in the system files the definitions windows has set for tile sizes or grid layout?

Comment: No. It is not possible.